# SUM and COUNT inside a CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is attendancelogs table attached below.

```
         Code    Name    Date        day1          Status
       -------  ------  ---------    --------    -------------------
         724    Ramesh  1-May-14    Thursday       Present 
         724    Ramesh  2-May-14    Friday         Present 
         724    Ramesh  3-May-14    Saturday       ½Present  On Leave(½CL)
         724    Ramesh  4-May-14    Sunday         WeeklyOff 
         724    Ramesh  5-May-14    Monday         ½Present  On Leave(½CL)
         724    Ramesh  6-May-14    Tuesday        ½Present  On Leave(½CL)
         724    Ramesh  7-May-14    Wednesday      Present 
         724    Ramesh  8-May-14    Thursday       ½Present 
         724    Ramesh  9-May-14    Friday         Present 
         724    Ramesh  10-May-14   Saturday       Present 
         724    Ramesh  11-May-14   Sunday         WeeklyOff  ½Present 
         724    Ramesh  12-May-14   Monday          Present 
         724    Ramesh  13-May-14   Tuesday         Present 
         724    Ramesh  14-May-14   Wednesday       Present 
         724    Ramesh  15-May-14   Thursday        Present 
         724    Ramesh  16-May-14   Friday          Present 
         724    Ramesh  17-May-14   Saturday        Present 
         724    Ramesh  18-May-14   Sunday         WeeklyOff 
         724    Ramesh  19-May-14   Monday           Present 
         724    Ramesh  20-May-14   Tuesday       Present  On Leave(½CL)
         724    Ramesh  21-May-14   Wednesday       ½Present 
         724    Ramesh  22-May-14   Thursday       Absent
         724    Ramesh  23-May-14   Friday           Present 
         724    Ramesh  24-May-14   Saturday         Present 
         724    Ramesh  25-May-14   Sunday           WeeklyOff 
         724    Ramesh  26-May-14   Monday            Present 
         724    Ramesh  27-May-14   Tuesday         Present 
         724    Ramesh  28-May-14   Wednesday       Present 
         724    Ramesh  29-May-14   Thursday       Present 
         724    Ramesh  30-May-14   Friday          Present 
         724    Ramesh  31-May-14   Saturday         Present
```

Expected output is:

```
       EmployeeCode      EmployeeName   Monday      Saturday      TotalLeaves
       -------------    --------------  -------     ----------    ------------
          724              Ramesh        0.5         0.5             4(days)
```

I am trying to get the number of leaves on Monday and Saturday in a month based on Status Column

My query is

```
    select EmployeeCode
           ,EmployeeName
           ,AttendanceDate
           ,datename(dw,AttendanceDate) as 'day1'
           ,InTime
           ,a.PunchRecords
           ,a.Status 
    from   AttendanceLogs a 
    join   Employees b on a.EmployeeId=b.EmployeeId 

    where  AttendanceDate  >='2014-05-01'    
    and    AttendanceDate <='2014-05-31' 
    and    EmployeeCode='724'
    and    datename(dw,AttendanceDate) IN('Monday','Saturday') 
    and    a.Status!='present'

   order by AttendanceDate
```

Please help me to get the expected output.

Comment: Please don't post images but the data as text, then we can copy-paste it to sql-fiddle to create the schema and data and test our query. [Links will also rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) in future.

Comment: Please build a working SQL fiddle and also post it here, so we can help you better

Comment: Business rule wise, how do you figure 4 days off for the above data? What do you do with the WeeklyOff 1/2Present record? or the Present On Leave(1/2CL)?  Since your status seems to be a combination of various parts, is there a way to get it split up into each piece via your database, or is it stored in that weird manner?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess something like this:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT  code ,
        name ,
        [date] ,
        CASE WHEN [status] LIKE '1/2Present%' THEN 0.5
             WHEN [status] = 'Absent' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END AS StatusAdder
FROM    tablename
WHERE   attendancedate >= '2014-05-01'
        AND attendancedate <= '2014-05-31'
        AND code = '724'
)

SELECT  code ,
        name ,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) = 2 THEN SUM(statusAdder) END AS Monday ,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, date) = 7 THEN SUM(statusAdder) END AS Saturday ,
        SUM(statusAdder) AS TotalLeaves
FROM    cte
GROUP BY code ,
        name
```

You'll have to adjust to with your object names.